# Where is Cortex-M4 hardware breakpoint address?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, cortex-m, openocd

m4 debug feature, 
I'm using stm32f407 discovery with openocd, gdb in ubuntu

I'm trying to understad breakpoint feature,
I can set breakpoint address in openocd with gdb and chip will stop when pc run to that address

like main function is at 0x8008000,
I guess there must be a register to store this address(0x8008000), but I cannot find where is this register
I found FP_COMP0~FP_COMP7 in FPB manual, but in gdb it show always 0, and I think it's for new addres that tranform to.

Can anyone tell me where to learn related info, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, these are the `FP_COMP0`-`FP_COMP7` registers in the FPB (Flash Patch and Breakpoint Unit) - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/BABGEDIG.html.

This does work, just tested it in practice (4 breakpoints set):

[image]

Just make sure that when using IDE it may cache previously read register values and setting a breakpoint will not immediately show in the memory you see through IDE. Forcing it to refresh (e.g. by running and pausing the program) will cause it to show the correct values.

Comment: I was wondering the exact same thing - why FP_COMP0~FP_COMP7 were always zero, even though I had breakpoints installed. The reason was that I was looking at the Eclipse memory view which works only when the target is suspended, but GDB actually removes the breakpoints on suspend and re-inserts them before continuing. When I resume the target and inspect the memory with OpenOCD I could see the FP_COMP0~FP_COMP7 as expected.